# Open settings programmatically in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios11

I am opening the device settings page from my app.When I open through iPhone X(iOS11) and iPhone 8 it goes to app settings . But when I open through iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone SE it goes to home settings page.
**I need to open home settings page of iPhone like iPhone 8 Plus(open home settings page)** .  I am running the below code.

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *settingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[application openURL:settingsURL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Opened url");
    }
}];
```

My problem is, I created a new project and I ran this above code . Its working fine.And I can able to navigate to device home settings page in same iPhone X.
But when I run this code in my project in iPhone X it goes to app settings screen.I don't know where I missed.
Please help me if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Global Variable
>
> UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
>
> Used to create a URL that you can pass to the openURL: method. When you open the URL built from this string, the system launches the Settings app and displays the app’s custom settings, if it has any.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring?language=objc

This is from Apple official document. My guess is your app have its own setting page, that's why `openURL` function takes you to app's setting page instead of Setting home.